# How to post arrays in java

Tags: java, okhttp

I am a new programmer and I have a question that is easy for you and difficult for me, how to send an array or object to a header in java, for example

````
header = new HashMap<>();


header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");


javob = new Gson().fromJson("{\"arr\": [1, 2]}", new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());


net.setHeaders(header);


net.setParams(javob, RequestNetworkController.REQUEST_PARAM);


net.startRequestNetwork(RequestNetworkController.POST, "https://test.uz/api/v1/demo_test/random", "", _net_request_listener);```


**{"arr": [1, 2]}**
````

Comment: What do you mean by "send an array or object to a header"? Which header is it? And what do you want to set the value of the header to? Do you really need to put the array in a header? Or do you mean that you want to send the array as the body?

Comment: I need to post data to the site

Comment: Check this out. https://square.github.io/okhttp/. Lot's ofinfo about okHttp here as well, https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp. 
If you already have an idea about these basics andyou are still struggling, please share some more code.

Comment: To post data, you probably don't want it to be in a header. You probably need to serialize the array as JSON and add it to the body of the request. You will need to read the documentation of the API you are using to learn exactly what the JSON should look like.